# I need AppCompatActivity but the MapTabActivity extends already SupportMapFragment

Tags: android

I'm getting errors for not extending `AppCompatActivity`.

How do I solve this?

I've market with **HERE** the places the errors are found

Can I replace the "this" with something else?

I have seen that you can make your own toolbar , would that work?

MapTabActivity.java

```
package com.example.game1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;

public class MapTabActivity extends SupportMapFragment
    implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
int Latitute;
int Longitute;
LatLng latLon;


   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_map, container, false);
    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mapFrag = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mGoogleMap=googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);



    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, **HERE**
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    //zoom map camera
    // Get LocationManager object
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService **<-HERE** (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Get Current Location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    //latitude of location
    double myLatitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    //longitude og location
    double myLongitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLon = new LatLng(myLatitude, myLongitude);
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLon,17));
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this) **HERE**
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,**HERE**
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{

    // Elegxos gia to an eftases se marker
    //liga dekadika

}


public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
private void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)**HERE**
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,**HERE**
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                    .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapTabActivity.this,**HERE**
                                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,**HERE**
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,**HERE**
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();**HERE**
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}

[you can see the errors in this picure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlvBg.png)

Comment: You are mixing up Activities and Fragments, check this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Comment: By the way, you don't need `getChildFragmentManager`   . Your current class here already is a SupportMapFragment, so you should not load another one

Answer (score 0):

You are using [**`SupportMapFragment`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment), so try with

[**`getActivity()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()) or  [**`getContext ()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext%28%29).

> **`getActivity()`**- Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.
>
> **`getContext ()`** Returns the context the view is running in, through which it can access the current theme, resources, etc.

**Example**

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: @PhilippSch add `getContext()` instead of `this`

Comment: @PhilippSch let me inform.

Comment: that wont work here:' ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}'

or here: '(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)'

will it? 

and what about this?                         'ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapTabActivity.this,
                                    new String[]'

Comment: @PhilippSch `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getContext(),`

Comment: thank you , and sorry for the long comment im a new user

Comment: @PhilippSch Kindly check my answer. Let me inform .